# Empty, Clear, Delete modifier field using python - MeshDeform

Tags: python, modifiers

trying to clear the Object field of a MeshDeform modifier on selected objects. My current code populates the field but I would like to check if the field is empty and then clear it if it's not. I realize I could just replace the variable but I would just like to empty the field on occasion.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    selected = obj.name
    s3 = 'ColCube'
    
    bpy.data.objects[selected].modifiers["MeshDeform"].object = bpy.data.objects[selected[:selected.index(".")] + s3 + selected[selected.index("."):]]
```

Comment: Add `if obj.modifiers["MeshDeform"].object: obj.modifiers["MeshDeform"].object = None` into the loop to clear field if not empty

Comment: Of course! it makes so much sense! Thank you!